# How to use print in data grip

Tags: sybase, datagrip

How can I use the function print from sybase ase 16 in a script in datagrip? It is working fine when using aqua data studio but datagrip is showing an error for each print in the script.

Comment: What do you mean with print? Please, elaborate on that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X69372.htm

when using something simple as print "Berkeley author" from the docu example it will show an error for the function print. I am not able to run any sybase script which is including a print function on datagrip. everytime I am opening such a script to run it, datagrip will show an error in line XY where the print function is. they are all working fine running them directly in the console or with aqua data studio.

Comment: Please attach the screenshot with teh problem. We've just checked and it seems to work.